# how to align the table side by side based on the class of the table

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am getting the row id from database. If the rowid is same then i want to display them in same row. Else i want to display them in different row. I am using the kendo ui list view control. The list view items should be aligned based on the rowid.

my records will come from the database like

```
 id   name     rowid
  1   first      1
  2   second     1
  3   third      2
  4   fourth     2
  5   fifth      3
  6   sixth      4
  7   seven      5
  8   eight      5
```

Then the out put will be in the form like

```
  first          second
  third          fourth
  fifth
  sixth
  seven           eight
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to sure that your records  from database were `ordered` by `rowid`.

Then your list-view template should like this:

```
<div style="width: 400px;">
    <script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="template">
        <div style="float: left;height: 100px; width:#=getColWidth(rowid,data)#px;">
            #=name#
        </div>
    </script>
</div>

<script>
function getColWidth(currentRowID,data)
{
    var dataLen = data.length, 
        numberOfColumn=0, 
        columnWidth,
        rowWidth = 400; /**suppose that your Row take 400 pixel in View*/

    for(var i = 0; i < dataLen; i++)
    {
        if(data.rowid == currentRowID)
        {
            numberOfColumn++;
        }
    }
    columnWidth = Math.round(rowWidth/numberOfColumn);
    return columnWidth;
}
</script>
```